# Eclipse Console output stops working after Tomcat start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I regularly run a v8.5 Apache Tomcat server on my develop machine inside of Eclipse (currently v4.22.0, but I've had this issue for some time now). Typically, everything works fine; I write my code, it publishes to the Tomcat server if it's hot-swappable or I restart the Tomcat if not, and either way I can access/debug/watch the console to observe application behavior.

Occasionally however, the console output seems to break. I'll start my server, and see the initial boiler-plate startup sequence colored red in console (because it's written to standard error, I believe). However after server startup, that's it. The server is actually up, I can interact with it and it all works perfectly fine, but no messages are written to the console at all from that point on. Restarting Tomcat/Eclipse/my computer at this point will do no good; I typically need to actually delete and re-create the Tomcat server inside of Eclipse to be able to observe console output again. Better than the first few times I ran into this issue (I ended up completely re-doing my Eclipse setup!) but still irksome when I'm unlucky enough to hit this multiple times close together. It seems obvious that something is getting hung up somewhere (probably inside of the Tomcat server?) but I have no idea what/where. Anyone have an idea on what's really going wrong here/how to resolve this in a less destructive manner than once again setting up a new Tomcat server in Eclipse? To be clear, this will typically work for months at a time before occurring, but occurrences do seem somewhat random in nature; occasionally I'll have it'll happen almost immediately w/ a new server instance.

Have tried restarting Tomcat/Eclipse/my computer. No difference.
Have pulled down new instance of codebase and recreated Eclipse project. No difference.
Have completely reinstalled a new version of Eclipse. Problem went away, for a while.
Have completely recreated a new Tomcat server in Eclipse. Problem went away, for a while.